# How to create generic view with viewcontroller for iOS5?

Tags: ios, ios5, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I'd like to develop for iOS5 and have a storyboard...
I've just created UIView with UIViewController on the storyboard.
I have added a lot of other UIButtons and labels and creates outlets to VC.

I would like to use this view with it's viewcontroller 3 times on a single parent view.
How is it possible? I dont want to copy "a lot of other UIButtons and labels" ...

Maybe i should create this view out of storyboard in separate XIB? How will i use XIB in storyboard?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Thanx you, [Juzzz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874249/juzzz) - your solution works perfect:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create 2 custom viewControllers (one for each view in your story board.
example:

```
@interface GraphCollectionViewController : UIViewController

@interface GraphViewController : UIViewController
```

To connect them you can use something called: UIViewController containment

For your GraphCollectionViewController create 3 outlets for your UIViews. Then create 3 properties of GraphViewController's (or an array, what you want) and initialize them in the view did load.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *topView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *middleView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *bottomView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) GraphViewController *topGraphViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) GraphViewController *middleGraphViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) GraphViewController *bottomGraphViewController;

...

//top graph
    self.topGraphViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GraphViewController"]; //init with view from storyboard
    self.topGraphViewController.view.frame = self.topView.bounds; //set frame the same

    [self.view addSubview:self.topGraphViewController.view];
    [self addChildViewController:self.topGraphViewController];
    [self.topGraphViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

//middle graph
    self.middleGraphViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GraphViewController"]; //init with view from storyboard
    self.middleGraphViewController.view.frame = self.middleView.bounds; //set frame the same

    [self.view addSubview:self.middleGraphViewController.view];
    [self addChildViewController:self.middleGraphViewController];
    [self.middleGraphViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

//bottom graph
    self.bottomGraphViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GraphViewController"]; //init with view from storyboard
    self.bottomGraphViewController.view.frame = self.bottomView.bounds; //set frame the same

    [self.view addSubview:self.bottomGraphViewController.view];
    [self addChildViewController:self.bottomGraphViewController];
    [self.bottomGraphViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I think you get the point. For more understanding [this example](https://github.com/peterfriese/UIViewControllerContainmentSample) .

Comment: Good, except lines like `self.bottomView.bounds` discard the placeholder view's origin. Use `self.bottomView.frame` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new view class (with it's own .h, .m files) and base this on the ViewController you created yourself.

So as for code:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
```

Let's say the above is your original ViewController that you want to use in other places.
This has buttons, labels, etc. in it.

When you create a new view class base it on your own instead of UIViewController class like this:

```
@interface MyNewController : ViewController
```

Now that MyNewController is based on ViewController you created earlier, it should have it's buttons, labels, etc. you created as well.

Edit: You might also have to change your view's base class in the storyboard.
Click on the view you want to change, look at the right hand side attributes window, under Custom Class choose your own controller, in this case ViewController.

Comment: I've created my own View class and ViewController class. I don't want to copy other elements witch are on my View... buttons and others... ViewController uses them..

Comment: Right, so if you base your class on your "generic" class, you shouldn't have to copy paste the buttons and etc. They should automatically get imported.

Comment: Generic i mean i would like to use it many times with different Model (data)

Comment: Maybe if you could post some code, I could help better, but the above example I gave should work.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/iosdev/viewcontroller/ See what he is doing with the DemoViewController towards the end.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10070/discussion-between-k06a-and-c0d3junk13)